# Relevant url in file Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm uploading an image to my site using the following  code, 
The Image uploading just fine but, how ever 
I need to fix the following things :
 -I'm getting this kind of Url 
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wow\WowMvc5\WowMvc5\images\gallery\Picture 022.jpg, 
Instead of relevant folder Url 
-I thing in order to avoid an error of 2 images this the same name it would be better to create a folder under images for each image (or any better idea )
Thank you for your time

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "TakeAwayId,TakeAwayName,description,Price,DishUrl,quantity,DishesAmount,GenreId")] TakeAway takeaway)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/gallery/");
        foreach (string item in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item];
            if (file.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            string SavedFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            SavedFileName = Server.MapPath
                ("~" + "/images/gallery/" + SavedFileName);

            file.SaveAs(SavedFileName);
            takeaway.DishUrl = SavedFileName;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.takeaway.Add(takeaway);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.genre, "GenreId", "GenreName", takeaway.GenreId);
        return View(takeaway);
    }
```

Comment: uploading image is fine but you need to provide unique name for each image on your folder. create new folder with each image it is not correct way.

Comment: Thanks, can u direct me to how ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is name and save each picture using a **HashCode**.

By definition, It's *very* improbable that 2 different strings, when transformed using a hash algorithm, will have the same output. Just to be sure, add a random string to the original name of the image.

```
string newName = (oldName + random).GetHashCode().ToString()
```

Comment: Ok. Good advice I will do so. This answer to that Q My biggest problem is about the Url

Answer (score 0):

filename_1.jpg
 where cnt is incremental count
    if(file.exists()
    {
    string cnt =  file.split("*");
    String newFileName  = filename+"*"+(cnt+1)+".jpg";
    }

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I really didn’t understand